# How to use processing sketch in a web app

Tags: java, jsp, processing

Good day, i have a Processing sketch that i want to use in a web application
i am using jsp and servlets in my web app with tomcat as a server. I am using netbeans and i tried using < applet > tag but i can't get it to work, please help.

CODE:

import processing.core.*;

```
public class MyProcessingSketch extends PApplet {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    PApplet.main(new String[] {  "MyProcessingSketch" });
  }

  public void setup() {


  }
@Override 
  public void draw() {
   background (200,0,0);
  }

  public void settings(){
       size(600,240);
  }


  public void mousePressed(){
            exit(); 
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applets are not really supported anymore... But you might try [p5js](http://p5js.org/). Your HTML page would look like this:

```
<html>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.6/p5.js"></script>
<script>

  function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 240);
    background(200,0,0);
  }

  function draw() {
   // ...
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks. Btw, is openpixelcontrol supported in p5js because we will be using it to control fadecandy.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. However, you could send messages from your webpage (p5js or simple js) to a java-based webserver (tomcat or grizzly or whatever) that can then run your OPC code

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer says, applets are pretty much dead. They currently require you to have a paid signed certificate or for your users to change their security settings. And even then they show a bunch of scary warning dialogs, and it's just a pain in the neck for everybody. [Chrome has dropped support for applets](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml), and [they'll be deprecated in the next version of Java](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

If you're using eclipse, you've got three options:

- Deploy as a runnable jar.
- Deploy as a packaged executable.
- Deploy using webstart.

None of these are embedding an applet in a webpage.

However, if you're using the Processing editor, you can use [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) to write the same Processing code but have it deployed as JavaScript, which you can embed in a webpage. Processing.js does the translation for you, so you don't have to change your code into JavaScript code.

You can also use [p5.js](https://p5js.org/), but that will require you to completely rewrite your syntax into JavaScript syntax.

In either case, you'll no longer be able to use Java libraries in your code. You'll have to find a JavaScript library that does the same things and use that instead. If you really need to use the Java libraries, then you have to go with deploying using one of the first three options.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, is openpixelcontrol supported in p5js because we will be using it to control fadecandy.

Comment: @KatyaCipriano You'll have to look to see whether that library offers a JavaScript version. If it only has a Java version, then you won't be able to deploy it as JavaScript.

Comment: Hi, it has examples for node.js